# Multiplication in Deligne cohomology: explicit formula for p = q= 1

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

In the very beginning of [1] the geometric meaning of Deligne cohomology $H^q(X, \mathbb{Z}(p))_D$ and multiplicative structure on it is being discussed. In particular, it is not hard to see that $H^q(X, \mathbb{Z}(1))$ can be canonically identified with $H^{q-1}(X, \mathcal{O}^{\times}_X)$.

The group $H^2(X, \mathbb{Z}(2))_D$ is identified with the group of holomorphic rank $1$ bundles with holomorphic connection (group structure is given by tensor product)

The $\cup$-multiplication gives us a map
$$
H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}(1))_D \otimes H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}(1))_D = H^0(X, \mathcal{O}^{\times}_X) \otimes H^0(X, \mathcal{O}^{\times}_X) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{Z}(2))_D
$$
In other words, given two nowhere vanishing holomorphic functions $f$ and $g$ on $X$ we obtain a holomorphic line bundle with holomorphic connection on $X$.

Though in [1] the explicit formula for this in terms of Čhech cocycles is given, I am looking for another description of the same operation.

First of all, observe that each pair of functions $f, g \in H^0(X, \mathcal{O}^{\times}_X)$ define a holomorphic map $F_{f,g} \colon X \to (\mathbb{C}^{\times})^2$. Following Esnault and Viehweg,  denote the resulting line bundle with holomorphic connection $f \cup g$ by $r(f, g)$. Then it seems clear from functoriality reasons that $$r(f, g) = F_{f,g}^*r(z,w),$$ where $z$ and $w$ are coordinate functions on $\mathbb{C}^{\times}\times \mathbb{C}^{\times}$. Thus, I'd be happy to understand, what $r(z, w)$ is.

Since $(\mathbb{C}^{\times})^2$ is a product of two Stein manifolds, there are no non-trivial holomorphic line bundles. Therefore, the only ''interesting'' part of $r(z,w)$ is the holomorphic connection. Any holomorphic connection on trivial bundle is given by $\nabla = d + \eta$, where $\eta$ is a holomorphic $1$-form. So my questions are:

- What is this $1$-form $\eta$ on $\mathbb{C}^{\times} \times \mathbb{C}^{\times}$? It seems to me, that $\frac{dz}{z} - \frac{dw}{w}$ would be nice (at least, if this is the case, it satisfies the properties of $r(f, g)$ given in [1]), however I'm not able do deduce this explicitly form Esnault-Viehweg formulas.
- From my speculations it follows that the underlying line bundle for any $r(f,g)$ is trivial. Is this at least true? If not, than where is my mistake?

Thank you for any comments!

[1] -- H. Esnault, E. Viehweg. Deligne-Beilinson cohomology. in: Beilinson's Conjectures on Special Values of L-Functions ( Ed.: Rapoport, Schappacher, Schneider ). Perspectives in Math. 4, Academic Press (1988) 43 - 91 
(http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/esnault/preprints/ec/deligne_beilinson.pdf)

Comment: Vassily, I suggest you using MathOverflow for this kind of question

Comment: If you're asking a question about a detail from a paper from the last 40 years, MO is probably the place to do it as the above user suggests.

Comment: Why not define clearly your map $(f,g) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{Z}(2))_D$ where $f,g$ are holomorphic $X\to \Bbb{C}^*$

Comment: for those viewing this question, is has been answered on MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/330846/73622)